# Primary key -Primary Index in DB2 Vs Primary Key - Clustered index in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, database-migration, sql-server-migration-assi

Primary Index in DB2 Vs Clustered index in SQL. While migrating db2 to SQL i came to know that primary key in db2 is creating primary index not clustered index.

I found primary index is different from clustered index in DB2 is it correct? In that case which index we need to use in SQL?

Comment: Just declare the column(s) as the primary key.  Clustered indexes are an implementation detail.  You only need to use them if you know how to use them.

Comment: Yes i have done the same. but my doubt raises when DB2 create primary index while creating Primary key while SQL create clustered index when creating primary key.

Comment: . . They are both indexes that accomplish the sample purpose with respect to the primary key.  It is like caring whether you are flying on a Boeing or Airbus.  They are different, but if you don't know or care about the differences, you can just book the flight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL Server Clustered Index is basically like the following index in DB2

```
CREATE INDEX ... ON ... (pk-columns) INCLUDE (all-other-columns)
```

I.e. it is useful if your main use of this index is to fetch by the pk-columns and select many other columns.

As this index contains all columns, there is no separate table structure (no heap table) for SQL Server tables that have a clustered index.

IMHO the clustered index is heavily over used in SQL Server. I wrote this article to explain one problem clustered indexes introduce:

- https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key